# Как взять данные со сделки? AmoCrm

Tags: php, api

Авторизовался через Oauth2.0 пытаюсь взять данные со сделки, но пишет `401 [detail] => Неверный логин или пароль )`

вот пытаюсь взять данные

```
$queryUrl = 'https://xxxxx.amocrm.ru/api/v4/leads';
$access_token = $accessToken;
    $curl = curl_init();
    
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => $queryUrl,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $queryData,
    ));
    
    $result = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $result = json_decode($result, 1);

    print_r($result);
```

Выводит только `Array ( [title] => Unauthorized [type] => https://httpstatus.es/401 [status] => 401 [detail] => Неверный логин или пароль )`

Хотел чтобы выводила вот так >

```
"leads": [
    {
        "id": 1184303,
        "name": "Новый тест 2",
        "price": 0,
        "responsible_user_id": 6726247,
        "group_id": 0,
        "status_id": 40736470,
        "pipeline_id": 4379983,
        "loss_reason_id": null,
        "created_by": 0,
        "updated_by": 0,
        "created_at": 1623860529,
        "updated_at": 1623860529,
        "closed_at": null,
        "closest_task_at": null,
        "is_deleted": false,
        "custom_fields_values": null,
        "score": null,
        "account_id": 29544991,
```

Comment: _Авторизовался через Oauth2.0 пытаюсь взять данные со сделки, но пишет_ - пишет не  авторизовались...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если уже получен access_token (в Вашем коде непонятная строка `$access_token = $accessToken;`) то нужно его передавать в заголовке

```
$headers = [
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $accessToken
];

$curl = curl_init();
    
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
    CURLOPT_HTTPGET => 1, // CURLOPT_HTTPGET вместо CURLOPT_POST
    CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $queryUrl,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers  // передаём заголовки
));
    
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$result = json_decode($result, 1);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Выдаёт "Пустое тело запроса при типе запроса POST'

Comment: CURLOPT_HTTPGET вместо CURLOPT_POST и удалите CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS